# Return JSON Response in Laravel Validation

Tags: laravel

I have this validation code that check if my input is a valid image with max size of `2048`:

```
$request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
]);
```

If the validation doesn't pass, I'd like to return a response in JSON format, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You request must have the `Accept` header set to `application/json`.

Once it's done, every responses from Laravel will be in json.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
$rules = ['file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'] ; 
$validator = Validator::make($request->file , $rules) ; 
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'there is been an error', 'error message' => $validator->errors()]);
        }
```